# Find value after a particular set of characters in the string

Tags: string, batch-file, find

So I am looking to run a batch file which would extract the value of a particular variable from a string. For Example:

```
[2017-11-03T12:18:56.263733+00:00] [XFM] [TRACE:1] [EPMHFM-00000] [XFM] [ecid: XDS.0000.0000.0000.0001] [File: CHsvDSSystemInfo.cpp] [Line: 6002] [userId: ] [appName: GGCOST] [pid: 9640] [tid: 6632] [host: AWEU1ORHYAP05P] [nwaddr: 172.20.36.105:0;] [errorCode: 0] [srcException: NotSpec] [errType: 1] [dbUpdate: 1] [11.1.2.4.202.5211]  [[SYSINFO:Application=GGCOST; PID=9640; NumUsers=0; CPU(Cores)=8; NumTasks=0; NumErrors=1; PhysicalMem=60129071104; UsedPhysicalMem=38635540480; ProcUsedPhysicalMem=3277619200; VirtualMem=140737488224256; UsedVirtualMem=5590806528; ProcUsedVirtualMem=3582775296; UsedCPU=9.3284; ProcUsedCPU=56.3594; NumCubesInRAM=7007; NumDataRecordsInRAM=1693604; NumRecordsInLargestCube=92334]]
```

From the above string, I am looking to extract the pid number, which in this case is 6212. Can it be done via a batch script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "var=[2017-11-11T07:27:23.088173+00:00] [XFM] [TRACE:1] [EPMHFM-00000] [XFM] [ecid: ] [File: XFMDataSource.cpp] [Line: 508] [userId: ] [Msg arguments: ] [appName: MyApp] [pid: 6212] [tid: 3176] [host: Server1] [nwaddr: 172.24.62.192:0;] [errorCode: 0] [srcException: NotSpec] [errType: 1] [[XDS: XFMDataSource process exiting now ...]] "
SET "var1=%var:(= %"
SET "var1=%var1:)= %"
SET "result=not found "
FOR %%a IN (%var1%) DO IF "%%a"=="[pid:" (
  SET "result="
 ) ELSE ( 
  IF NOT defined result SET result=%%a
 )
SET "result=%result:~0,-1%"

ECHO result is %result%

GOTO :EOF
```

So yes, it's possible. This is one of many ways.

first set `result` to a report-string, then use the standard `for` functionality on the string `var`. When the predecessor string `[pid:` is found, set `result` to *nothing* so that when the `for` delivers the next string to `%%a`, `result` will be undefined and `%%a` will not be `[pid:` - then set `result` to the string found (which means `result` is now defined)

After processing the remaining strings, all that is required is to remove the final character from `result`.

Another approach would be

```
FOR %%a IN (%var:]=%) DO IF "%%a"=="[pid:" (
```

which would replace the `]` characters with *nothing* which would mean that the value set as `result` would not require the removal of the last character so the `set` following the `for` loop would not be required.

I've inserted two lines to remove the `(` and `)` which would cause a problem with the new data you've posted. Note that a new variable, `var1` is derived and processed.

There are a number of characters which cause `cmd` problems and require special processing. `!` will cause problems if `delayedexpansion` is invoked, but we need to know this type of information *before* devising a solution as it **a**ffects the code required.

The code will find the string following *last* appearance of the string `[pid:` in the variable. The string following `PID` will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks it did work for that particular example. However, I guess the example I gave was not robust enough. I have updated the example since and it doesn't appear to work for it, though it should since I believe the for loop only takes into account the first pid value correct?  Also I have set enabledelayedexpansion earlier, does it effect the code?

Comment: I tried several tests on the code and it appears that %%a is taking in the entire line in the first iteration rather than only picking up until the space. Any idea why?

Comment: I can't see your tests, but I'd conclude that your variable is "quoted"

Comment: Indeed you are right. But if I don't put the quote, it says "8 was unexpected"

Comment: However thanks. The updated quote now works perfectly!

Comment: Ah, yes - but the `8 is unexpected` is symptomatic of a `)` within the string being processed. `cmd` interprets this as the end of the `(list)` hence since it's not wanted, processing to eliminate it. `(` processed similarly to keep the universe in balance.

Answer (score 1):

Another method, [I learned just yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47230335/2152082)

```
@echo off

>t.txt echo [2017-11-03T12:18:56.263733+00:00] [XFM] [TRACE:1] [EPMHFM-00000] [XFM] [ecid: XDS.0000.0000.0000.0001] [File: CHsvDSSystemInfo.cpp] [Line: 6002] [userId: ] [appName: GGCOST] [pid: 9640] [tid: 6632] [host: AWEU1ORHYAP05P] [nwaddr: 172.20.36.105:0;] [errorCode: 0] [srcException: NotSpec] [errType: 1] [dbUpdate: 1] [11.1.2.4.202.5211]  [[SYSINFO:Application=GGCOST; PID=9640; NumUsers=0; CPU(Cores)=8; NumTasks=0; NumErrors=1; PhysicalMem=60129071104; UsedPhysicalMem=38635540480; ProcUsedPhysicalMem=3277619200; VirtualMem=140737488224256; UsedVirtualMem=5590806528; ProcUsedVirtualMem=3582775296; UsedCPU=9.3284; ProcUsedCPU=56.3594; NumCubesInRAM=7007; NumDataRecordsInRAM=1693604; NumRecordsInLargestCube=92334]]

for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('"setx /F t.txt /D ] dummyVar /R 0,1 [pid:"') do set "var=%%a" & goto continue
:continue
set "var=%var:~0,-1%"
echo %var%
```

Cons: needs a file; creates a permanent environment variable (which of course can easily be deleted)